# Append Page to Domain Name Via Form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, redirect

***This is probably hopelessly simple, but I'm pulling my hair out!***

I am trying to create an input field that will allow users to input a text string that once submitted is appended to a domain name, taking the user to a page.

The process is as follows:

User inputs 'foo' into an input box.  Once submit is clicked, 'foo' is prefixed by http://example.com/ and (ideally) suffixed by .html (or .php) and the browser resolves to that address, ie http://example.com/foo.html.

Is this possible? My form kung foo is (clearly) not very strong, so any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have now or what you have attempted.

Comment: Hi, to be honest all I've tried has been on Codepen so I don't have anything saved. I can't help thinking this is such a simple problem (clearly, I'm simpler!) which is why I can't find an easy answer.

Comment: Why don't you leave it up to the user to declare whether it's `.html` or `.php`?

Comment: I would like to take that option away from them. The reason is so the user can be given a string 'qwerty' for example, that resolves to a page without them needing to add any further info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing the current URL can be done with `window.location.href`.

Setting the URL can be done in a similar manner. Given your situation, the following can be done:

```
yourForm.onsubmit = function() {
    var URLtext = document.getElementById("inputbox").value;
    window.location.href = window.location.href + URLtext; // this is for your current URL
}
```

Any well-formed URL wouldn't require the filetype unless you're accessing specific files in which case it's bad UI to programmatically find out what type of file it is. I'd leave it up to the user to determine filetype.

Comment: So my HTML would look something like this:

<form>
  <input type="text" id"inputbox"> 
</form>

And I'd use the script above?

Comment: Youd first declare `var yourForm = document.getElementById("inputbox");` and then use the script above.

Comment: I may be doing something stupid (still!) but I'm just getting a question mark appended to the end of the URL.

This is my code:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form>
  <input type="text" id"inputbox"> 
</form>

<script>
var yourForm = document.getElementById("inputbox");

yourForm.onsubmit = function() {
    var URLtext = document.getElementById("inputbox").value;
    window.location.href = window.location.href + URLtext; // this is for your current URL
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: That's beyond the scope of your original question sir

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll start a new question.  Thank you for your help so far :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "foo";

window.location = window.location.origin + "/" + string + ".html";
```